# Tensorflow and class intantiations. Do I need a separate graph for each instantiation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a quick question.  Consider, as an example, that I am writing a tensorflow program to model a single-layer perceptron that will perform boolean functions.  If I'm writing a class to contain that perceptron, will I need to create a separate graph using tf.graph for each instantiation of the class?

I.e. if I an modeling the boolean functions AND, OR and NAND, and I write a class Perceptron: 
         ...

Will I need to run tf.graph() in the **init** method for each class instantion  so that they're not using the same namespace? Or can I get away with defining scopes for each type of operation and only instantiate one class to perform all three types of operations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the overall architecture you want to give to your problem, in principle both solutions are correct.

If you foresee that you will need the models to interact (for instance create a cost function/inference that needs both models), then it is better to have all of them in the same graph, otherwise you will need to extract data through sessions to make them interact.

If instead you know that the models will never speak to each other, then I think it is a good practice to build them in separate graphs, to avoid unexpcted interactions (for instance, minimize the cost function of a model w.r.t. a variable that belongs to another model)

For this second solution, I like to structure classes in the following way (but I am not sure if this is good practice):

```
class MyModel(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.g = tf.Graph()
        self.sess = None

        with self.g.as_default():
            self.build_graph()

    def build_graph(self):
        # here all the logic to build the graph.
        # usually you store the outputs of the model in attributes
        # self.input_data_placeholder
        # self.target_data_placeholder
        # self.prediction
        # self.cost_tensor
        # self.learning_rate_placeholder
        # self.train_op
        # self.accuracy_tensor
        # self.init_op

    def open_session(self):
        if self.sess is None:
            sess = tf.Session(graph=self.g)
            sess.run(init_op)
        else:
            sess = self.sess
        return sess

    def predict(self, data):
        sess = self.open_session()
        pred = sess.run(
            self.prediction, 
            feed_dict={self.input_data_placeholder: data}
        )
        return pred

    def update(self, data, target, learning_rate):
        sess = self.open_session()
        cost, _ = sess.run(
            [self.cost_tensor, self.train_op],
            feed_dict={self.input_data_placeholder: data,
                       self.target_data_placeholder: target,
                       self.learning_rate_placeholder: learning_rate
                       }
        return cost
```

Now the class is hiding all the tensorflow related stuff, and you communicate with it with numpy.arrays